# Bootstrap 3 - jumbotron background image effect

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, html

Hi I'm trying to build a site with a jumbotron with a background image, which in itself is not hard:

HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
...
</div>
```

CSS: (which lies in my custom css file and is loaded after all over css).

```
.jumbotron {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background-image: url(../img/jumbotronbackground.jpg);
    background-position: 0% 25%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: black 0.3em 0.3em 0.3em;
}
```

Now this creates a jumbotron with a background image, but I would like to get it to do an effect which I find hard to describe but is seen on this webpage here: http://www.andrewmunsell.com
You can see as you scroll the jumbotron content text etc sort of scrolls up faster than the background image. What is this effect called and is it easy to achieve with bootstrap/html/css?

I've had a look at the HTML of the pay but it's a bit too complex for me to follow at the moment.

Thanks,
Ben.

EDIT: I tried to get the effect by an example provided by the first answer, which is located at boot ply.

However for me the background image shows up, and then as soon as a scroll even a little bit, the whole image disappears. If I use safari's inertial scroll to try and scroll beyond the top of the page, the background tries to move down into view again, so I think the image is loaded correctly, then as soon as a scroll even a little bit, the height is being manipulated in such away the image is moved totally of screen.  Below is my HTML, (a little bit ugly in  where tabs are placed but Jekyll put it together by including the Jumbotron header I'm trying to make the parallax effect for, page content, and a page footer.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hybridisation Recombination and Introgression Detection and Dating</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Site for the HybRIDS R package for analysing recombination signal in DNA sequences">
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" type="text/css"/>
    <style>
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var jumboHeight = $('.jumbotron').outerHeight();
        function parallax(){
            var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
            $('.bg').css('height', (jumboHeight-scrolled) + 'px');
        }
        $(window).scroll(function(e){
            parallax();
        });
    </script>
    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></sc\
ript>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="bg"></div>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <img src="./img/HybRIDSlogo.png" class="img-rounded">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <div class="page-header">
                    <h2> Hybridisation Recombination and Introgression Detection and Dating </h2>
                    <p> <h2> <small> Easy detection, dating, and visualisation for recombination, introgression and hybridisation events in genomes. </small> </h2> </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End of JumboTron -->

    <div class="container">

        PAGE CONTENT HERE

    <!-- Close the container that is opened up in header.html -->
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You see where I've included the Javascript near the top and the div of class bg and then the jumbotron.

My CSS is:

```
body {
    background-color: #333333;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.bg {
  background: url('../img/carouelbackground.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px; 
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.jumbotron {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    height: 350px;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: black 0.3em 0.3em 0.3em;
    background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: It's called parallax scrolling. Dr. Google knows of many examples and tutorials.

Comment: @StephenThomas is right, this is called Parallax.  There are a ton of resources around the web to help get you started with it.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

### Example: http://bootply.com/103783

One way to achieve this is using a `position:fixed` container for the background image and place it outside of the `.jumbotron`. Make the `bg` container the same height as the `.jumbotron` and center the background image:

```
background: url('/assets/example/...jpg') no-repeat center center;
```

**CSS**

```
.bg {
  background: url('/assets/example/bg_blueplane.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px; /*same height as jumbotron */
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.jumbotron {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  height: 350px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: black 0.3em 0.3em 0.3em;
  background:transparent;
}
```

Then use jQuery to decrease the height of the `.jumbtron` as the window scrolls. Since the background image is centered in the DIV it will adjust accordingly -- creating a parallax affect.

**JavaScript**

```
var jumboHeight = $('.jumbotron').outerHeight();
function parallax(){
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.bg').css('height', (jumboHeight-scrolled) + 'px');
}

$(window).scroll(function(e){
    parallax();
});
```

**Demo**

http://bootply.com/103783

Comment: This does not work for me, I'll update the question with how I've tried to replicate the example.

Comment: Here's another example: http://bootply.com/103820 (using a simple parallax plugin)

Comment: Is there any way to add background image link dynamically?

Comment: This is a great answer - it's simple and works beautifully. In my case, I had to add 70px to the parallax function for some reason - probably because of margin/padding/navbar not being taken into account but it was a simple fix.

Answer (score 6):

After inspecting the sample website you provided, I found that the author might achieve the effect by using a library called [Stellar.js](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/), take a look at the library site, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is to keep the background image fixed and just move the content on scroll. For that you have to simply use the following css property :

background-attachment: fixed;