# Bootstrap 3 - jumbotron dynamic background image

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create mobile web site with a jumbotron with a dynamic background image.

When the user enters his own link, I will provide a background image url from my web service.

In this link [Bootstrap 3 - jumbotron background image effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914711/bootstrap-3-jumbotron-background-image-effect) there is a solution for fixed background image, but I couldn't figure out how to change this dynamically, or add the image on-the-fly.

That would be great if you can help me,

Thanks,

Comment: Please post the code you have so far and we can help out from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't specified on which event the image should be changed and how. What you can do is, override the `background` property of the `.bg` class using the jQuery **[css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** method:

```
$('.bg').css('background',' url('+image_url+') no-repeat center center');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2xLRb/1/)**