# Bootstrap 3 : Changing Jumbotron height causes background image not to be centred on resizing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a jumbotron

```
<div class="jumbotron" id="intro">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
      </div>
</div>
```

with the following css

```
#intro
{
    background: url('../images/bg.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size:cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
.jumbotron
{
    min-height: 400px;
}
```

But when I resize the window, the image is not resized and centred. However, if I remove

```
.jumbotron
    {
        min-height: 400px;
    }
```

image is resized and centred properly.

Answer (score 0):

Hey this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914711/bootstrap-3-jumbotron-background-image-effect) I have referred earlier for the same kind of problem. To centre the image in jumbotron.

Answer (score 0):

Please change #intro id **background size to 100%** instead of **background size cover** please check below example I used  **background-size:100% 100%;**

```css
#intro
{
    background: url('https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/lights.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
.jumbotron
{
    min-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <div class="jumbotron" id="intro">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
      </div>
</div>
```